# AWS -a Configure Trigger to detect only directory creation and not files creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda

I am setting up a lambda function to get triggered only when a directory gets created in s3 and not the file

Example: {bucket-name}/a/b/c/d/

a , b, c, d are directories inside bucket.

I want to get a lambda function triggered when a key "d" (d is not a file, it is a directory) gets created.

Based on my research ,

1. Only Definite prefixes can be mentioned instead of mentioning {bucket-name}/*/
2. There is no specific filter in triggers to check for a directory creation. Files and directory creation are considered same as put object
   operation. I want to trigger only during directory creation at certain depth, here in this example - i do not want to trigger
   during directory/s3 key creation of a,b or c. I need to trigger only during directory creation of d (at deeper level). can this be done any ways while setting up a lambda trigger?

Answer (score 1):

S3 isn't a file system - it is an object store.  However, keys that end with a trailing "/" are generally treated as folders, so perhaps that is a way to check.

So I would have my lambda check to see if the object key had a trailing "/", and treat that as the folder creation.

Note that you can create file objects with a trailing "/", you just can't do that via the console, but if you have control over key creation you should be able to avoid that.

Edit:
<strike>To address the comment that you want the lambda to only trigger when a "folder" is created, not for every file added, this is not currently supported.  Unless you are dealing with billions of files, I would not worry too much about the lambda costs.  A function that takes 250ms to run with 256MB of RAM will cost you less than $5 per million objects.</strike>

Edit, July 2022:
You can accomplish this by adding an event notification on the bucket and putting "/" for the suffix.  You will only get notified when a "folder" is created.  (And I should also note that the console for S3 now allows creation of "folders")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i can have a logic in lambda function that does this check, this is after triggering the lambda.  my lambda has to get triggered only when a folder is created, i do not want to trigger my lambda everytime when a file or folder gets created and then pick only folders, by this way i am thinking about saving costs on lambda run.

Comment: @keerthi Have you found the solution for this? Even I am looking for this kind of implementation. PLease let me know

Comment: @RahulDiggi - I have updated the answer.  This is now possible using event notifications.